# Why is there no kotlin-stdlib-jdk11?

Tags: kotlin

I'm using Kotlin for backend development...

Is it because Kotlin 1.4 already supports it? Or kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 would suffice? Or Kotlin does not have plans to support JDK 11?

Please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` is a stdlib that has utility to Java 8 (or JDK 1.8), so is compatible with Java 11. It depends on `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` so is basically the base, and then jdk8 binding, and so on. Probably there wasn't much of a change from Java8 to Java11 so they didn't made a new dependency for that. You can change target compatibility to Java 11 using `tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11" }` to make the compilation go for Java 11.

Answer (score 69):

**TL;DR `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` can be successfully used with JDK 11.**

The motivation of splitting binaries by JDK 1.7 and JDK 1.8 is the dependency of the `jdk8` artifact on some APIs not available (e.g., `ThreadLocalRandom`) in older Java versions.

Currently, there is no need for a special standard library artifact for JDK 11 because Kotlin doesn't provide any APIs depending on it.

Update: just in case, if you use Kotlin Gradle Plugin, you don't need to specify Kotlin's standard library dependency manually since the plugin adds it to all the Kotlin source sets automatically.

Comment: Hi @phfsck if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I will also add that `kotlin-stdlib` can be used for java 1.6 and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` for all **after** JDK 8 including JDK 17 for example.